# What is the best css unit of measurement for 4k screens?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu that when rendered on a standard monitor it correctly displays directly underneath its menu item. However, on a 4k screen there is a 1 to 2 px spacing. Is there a better unit of measurement that would make it render the same?

Comment: You don't mention what unit you're using now... Take a look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I apologize. Pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I have found positioning using percentages works well for Web interfaces that need to be displayed on large displays.